# Calculate GPS coordinates at x meters

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spherical-geometry

I want to calculate a pair of GPS coordinates(lat,long) that is at x meters N/S/E/W from a known point (lat_old,long_old).

I have found the Haversine formula
http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/5/5/055b634f6fe6c8d370c9fa48613dd7f9.png
for a for the distance between a two points and I have tried to isolate  lat , but the formula I get (through wolfram alpha) is divided by havesine(long-long_old) , so i get a divide by 0, what am I doing wrong? Should I use other formula?

Comment: The question is not completely trivial, and important. However this is not "research math" and thus does not belong to this site. I recommend you to ask it on Math Exchange.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Oh sorry i didnt knew it

Comment: The question should be reformulated to make explicit, what the actual task is; if it is "inverting" the Haversine formula, then it may be worth a second look. If it is "only" about calculating the WGS84 coordinates of the destination, then it is not research level math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to do a little guessing in answering your question:

I suppose, you are given WGS84 coordinates and an ellipsoid that approximates the shape of the earth, and you have the task of finding the WGS84 coordinates, that has an offset of x meters to the east and y meters to the north.

In that case you don't need the Haversine formula; you rather need to know, that the cross sections of the ellipsoid are circles in case of planes, that are parallel to the equator and, ellipses in case of planes, that contain the north and south pole.

The hard part of your task is to calculate, what fraction of the cross-sectional ellipse's circumference the given y-meters correspond to (depends on latitude and, whether it is in north or south direction) and then multiply that fraction by 360°, which gives you the WG84-delta in south/north direction.
Once you have calculated that, you can calculate the radius of the circle, that is parallel to the equator and from the radius of that circle you can calculate, how many degrees your given x meters correspond to.

The Haversine formula is only needed to calculate the geodesic distance between two WGS84 coordinates, if you are given the parameters of the rotational ellipsoid, that approximates the earth's surface.